# Pushing a feature branch remotely in hg

Tags: mercurial, feature-branch

I cloned an `hg` repo and created a feature branch (via `hg branch myfeature`). I have staged & committed changes to it via `hg add .` and then subsequently `hg commit -m "My new feature branch."`.

I would now like to push those changes (in the branch; *not* as `default`) to the remote server (where I cloned the project from) so that other devs can code review the changes in the `myfeature` branch.

I found a blog that recommends using:

```
hg push --create-branch-remote
```

But this isn't working for me - any ideas where I'm going awry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like --new-branch is what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to read `hg help push` for **your** version of Mercurial

> ```
> ...
>     --new-branch            allow pushing a new branch
> ...
> ```